# Error in declaring and assigning to string array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to declare an array out side the for loop and assign values to the string array. but i am getting an error. please give me a suggestion to do this. my code is given below.

```
    String[][] data=null; 

    for (int x = 0; x < dtm.getRowCount(); x++) {
            data  = {{"sds","sdsds"}}; <<< im getting error in here.
    }
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, headers);
```

Comment: if your problem solved please mark one of the best answers as accepted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
String[][] data = new String[dtm.getRowCount()][];
for (int x = 0; x < dtm.getRowCount(); x++) {
    data[x] = new String[]{"sds", "sdsds"};
}
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, headers);
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://ideone.com/YIKSAn)**.

Comment: i tried above code and it worked for me.. thnax for ur help buddy

Comment: @NimeshMadushan: Always glad to help :) If this answer helped you solve your problem, please mark it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to spot it easily.

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring the array in the wrong way. It should be:

```
 for (int x = 0; x < dtm.getRowCount(); x++) {
     data  = new String[][]{new String[]{"sds","sdsds"}};
 }
```

Anyway, with the code provided in the question, I don't get the reason for using a loop.

Comment: Am I understanding something wrong? To me, it looks as if this will create the `data` 2d-array multiple times and with only one row, and all except the last instance will be thrown away.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said `I don't get the reason for using a loop`.